# mod_rewrite with subdomain and url pattern

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache-config

I want to use the subdomain as a get variable with mod_rewrite AND use some parameter :

eg `/page/language/site/counter` -> `index.php?o=operator&lg=language&s=arg1&c=arg2`

How to do that with mod_rewrite?

```
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z]{3,6})\.example\.com  
RewriteRule ^index/([a-z]{2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})$  http://www.example.com/index.php?o=%1&lg=%2&site=%3&counter=%4 [NC,L] # for index.php
RewriteRule ^export/([a-z]{2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})$  http://www.example.com/export.php?o=%1&lg=%2&site=%3&counter=%4 [NC,L] # for export.php
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A `RewriteCond` does only belong to the directly following `RewriteRule`. So in your case both `RewriteCond` directives do only belong to the first `RewriteRule` directive and the second `RewriteRule` has no associated `RewriteCond` directives.

You can fix this in your example by merging the two `RewriteRule`s:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z]{3,6})\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(index|export)/([a-z]{2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})$ http://www.example.com/$1.php?o=%1&lg=$2&site=$3&counter=$4 [NC,L]
```

Also note the usage of `$n` instead of `%n` as `$n` refers to the match of the n-th group of `RewriteRule` the while `%n` refers to the match of the n-th group of the last successful `RewriteCond`.