# How mod_rewrite can add subdomain?

Tags: mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/ai?$ /Market/publish.jsp [QSA,L,PT]
RewriteRule ^/ar?$ /Market/MailDispatch [QSA,L,PT]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^web\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://web.example.com/$1 [L,R]
#How skip www\. to web\. for this 1 ? 
#RewriteRule ^/vi/?([0-9]+)\.htm$ /Market/vi.do?id=$1 [PT,L]                    
RewriteRule ^/li /Market/list.do [QSA,PT,L]
RewriteRule ^/vi/locations.jsp /Market/locations.jsp [PT,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.html
```

Nearly undoable(?) I try `http://example.com/vi/{N}.htm` should redirect to `http://web.example.com/vi/{N}.htm` where `N` is dynamic ID.

Seen [mod_rewrite with subdomain and url pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229385/mod-rewrite-with-subdomain-and-url-pattern)
There is no clear way to make eg `http://example.com/vi/1096.htm` pass up to next version `http://web.example.com/vi/1096.htm` where number is dynamic. I tried

Comment: What do you mean by "pass up to next version"? Based on your example, your existing code should do what you want (although maybe your `RewriteRule` statements shouldn't have leading `/`), so I think I'm misinterpreting your question; could you try and clarify what you mean?

Comment: Glad it works now meaning migrating template by template from LAMP to GAE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rule with the following scheme should do it:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/vi/\d+\.htm$ http://web.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

It’s important to put this rule in front of those rules that do an internal redirect. Otherwise an already internally rewritten URL could be rewritten externally.

If you want to use this rule in a .htaccess file, remove the leading slash from the pattern in `RewriteRule`.